# Is there a more strict Android java linter?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lint

While coding inside of XCode for iOS I have been linting with [Objective Clean](http://objclean.com/index.php), and while writing ruby code I have been linting with [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop), and both are strict not only about language idioms but also about things like whitespace and line formatting. The [built-in java linters](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) for Android Studio have no such opinions, it appears, and I wonder if there are any java linters for Android code or java coding standards for Android (that integrate into the editor) that get down to the level of whitespace, variable capitalization, etc?

Comment: "The built-in java linters for Android Studio have no such opinions" -- `lint`, going back to its origins, is not for "things like whitespace and line formatting". It is for pointing out syntax that, while valid, is probably not going to do what you think it will. Android's Lint rules follow that pattern. If you want code style enforcement, you will be looking for either IDEA plugins (since Android Studio is built on IDEA) or Gradle plugins (for running custom tasks to report problems). Or, as yole suggested in a comment, use the IDE's code formatter to reformat the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the [Checkstyle-IDEA plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065?pr=idea) from the plugin manager - it will report formatting errors for you.

Comment: +1 for that plugin. Very useful. There's also a good pre-commit hook gist here for Checkstyle: https://gist.github.com/davetron5000/37350

Comment: Can you recommend any blog posts that describe how to get this linter to work for Android on OSX? As far as I can tell, I have to still a) find or make a special Android-specific XML file, b) run (from the command line?) checkstyle every time I want it to lint, and then c) evaluate the report that is in a separate directory? This was after I had to literally hack a .plist file in the Android Studio binary on OSX so that it could start up with Checkstyle. I feel like Checkstyle should work here, but I cannot get it to and am unclear if it's the right tool. What are Google's devs using?

Comment: In my personal opinion, reviewing and correcting style linter reports manually is an exceedingly unproductive activity. It is far more efficient to apply the automatic code formatter, which is available out of the box in IntelliJ IDEA, and to get correct formatting for your entire project (or the desired subset thereof) in one step.